# Return filename only from full path in excel with vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a simple sheet in an Excel workbook:

```
Sheet1
+--A--+-----------B---------------------+
Item    Doc
A       C:\temp\docs\123_ProductInfo.pdf
B       C:\temp\docs\456_Install.pdf
```

I'd like to copy just the file name from column B to column C, like this:

```
Sheet1
+--A--+-----------B----------------------+---------C------------+
Item    Doc
A       C:\temp\docs\123_ProductInfo.pdf    123_ProductInfo.pdf
B       C:\temp\docs\456_Install.pdf        456_Install.pdf
```

I'm trying to do this with vlookup(), but I have no idea how to strip the file path. I tried using right(), but I'm striking out since I can't just look for a "\" character (because there are multiple in the path).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split cell into columns with `backslash` as the separator and grab the last variable. No formulas needed. (If it’s a one-off thing)

Comment: Otherwise `=MID(A2,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","*",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A2))` (assuming your data starts in cell `A2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't a one off thing the following formula should do the job:

```
=RIGHT([Cell with path];FIND("~";SUBSTITUTE([Cell with path];"\";"~";SUMPRODUCT(LEN([Cell with path])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([Cell with path];"\";""))))))
```

Explanation:

The sumproduct counts the number of times "\" is in the string.

Substitute changes the last occurence of "\" to "~".

Find is then able to find the position of the last "\" which is where we want our Right() to start from.